# Is there a way to disable IdleState?

Tags: c#, .net, netty

I am setting up a DotNetty server. My first handler is an IdleStateHandler .
Is there any way to disable this handler whan data is recieved, and then enable it after `WriteAndFlushAsync`?

```
public class TimeoutHandler :IdleStateHandler
{
    private bool enable = true;

    protected override void ChannelIdle(IChannelHandlerContext context, IdleStateEvent stateEvent)
    {        
         base.ChannelIdle(context, stateEvent);
    }

    public override void ChannelRead(IChannelHandlerContext context, object message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IdleState.ReaderIdle);

        NewIdleStateEvent(IdleState.ReaderIdle, false);

        base.ChannelRead(context, message);
    }

    public override Task WriteAsync(IChannelHandlerContext context, object message)
    {                                             
        return context.WriteAndFlushAsync(message as IByteBuffer); 
    }


    public TimeoutHandler(int readerIdleTimeSeconds, int writerIdleTimeSeconds, int allIdleTimeSeconds) : base(readerIdleTimeSeconds, writerIdleTimeSeconds, allIdleTimeSeconds)
    {

    }

    public TimeoutHandler(TimeSpan readerIdleTime, TimeSpan writerIdleTime, TimeSpan allIdleTime) : base(readerIdleTime, writerIdleTime, allIdleTime)
    {
    }

    public TimeoutHandler(bool observeOutput, TimeSpan readerIdleTime, TimeSpan writerIdleTime, TimeSpan allIdleTime) : base(observeOutput, readerIdleTime, writerIdleTime, allIdleTime)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handler will do that for you. If you're inheriting from `IdleStateHandler` all you really need to do is implement one or more of its constructors and override `ChannelIdle`. Here is a simple example which will close the connection after a specified period of inactivity; it will automatically reset itself when there is activity:

```
public class TimeoutHandler : IdleStateHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance firing <see cref="T:DotNetty.Handlers.Timeout.IdleStateEvent" />s.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="readerIdleTimeSeconds">
    ///     an <see cref="T:DotNetty.Handlers.Timeout.IdleStateEvent" /> whose state is <see cref="F:DotNetty.Handlers.Timeout.IdleState.ReaderIdle" />
    ///     will be triggered when no read was performed for the specified
    ///     period of time.  Specify <code>0</code> to disable.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="writerIdleTimeSeconds">
    ///     an <see cref="T:DotNetty.Handlers.Timeout.IdleStateEvent" /> whose state is <see cref="F:DotNetty.Handlers.Timeout.IdleState.WriterIdle" />
    ///     will be triggered when no write was performed for the specified
    ///     period of time.  Specify <code>0</code> to disable.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="allIdleTimeSeconds">
    ///     an <see cref="T:DotNetty.Handlers.Timeout.IdleStateEvent" /> whose state is <see cref="F:DotNetty.Handlers.Timeout.IdleState.AllIdle" />
    ///     will be triggered when neither read nor write was performed for
    ///     the specified period of time.  Specify <code>0</code> to disable.
    /// </param>
    public TimeoutHandler(int readerIdleTimeSeconds, int writerIdleTimeSeconds, int allIdleTimeSeconds) : base(readerIdleTimeSeconds, writerIdleTimeSeconds, allIdleTimeSeconds)
    {
    }

    protected override void ChannelIdle(IChannelHandlerContext context, IdleStateEvent stateEvent)
    {
        context.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

To add it to the pipeline with an inactivity period of 60 seconds (for *any* type of inactivity):

```
pipeline.AddLast(name: "idle-handler", new
   TimeoutHandler(readerIdleTimeSeconds: 60, writerIdleTimeSeconds: 60, allIdleTimeSeconds: 60));
```

It is worth looking at the source code for DotNetty's `IdleStateHandler` (given the lack of documentation). You will see for example that in `WriteAsync` upon completion of the write task it resets the `lastWriteTime`.